# How to fail a build on Scrutinizer based on phpcs output?

Tags: php, continuous-integration, static-code-analysis, phpcs, scrutinizer

I've tried configuring Scrutinizer to fail whenever the CodeSniffer analysis returns some errors with no luck.

Here's what I tried so far:

V1:

```
build:
  tests:
    override:
        command: './vendor/bin/phpcs ./src --report=checkstyle --report-file=cs-data'
        analysis:
          file: 'cs-data'
          format: 'php-cs-checkstyle'
```

V2:

```
build:
  tests:
    override:
      - 'phpcs-run'
```

My tools and `build_failure_conditions`:

```
tools:
  php_code_sniffer:
    config:
      standard: "PSR2"
checks:
  php:
    code_rating: true
    duplication: true
build_failure_conditions:
  - 'issues.label("coding-style").new.exists'
```

What's missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR; It looks like you're not specifying which folders to scan for errors.

Try using the following:

```
build:
  tests:
    override:
      - 'phpcs-run --standard=custom/standard/ruleset.xml --ignore=app/*/*/Test/ app/dir1/ app/dir2/ app/other/folder'
```

Some things that required clarification for me:

- scrutinizer currently does not support failing the phpcs command (similar to phpunit) as that would prevent the issues from being displayed in the UI.
- the workaround for that is to set-up a failure condition (which you already did) like for example whether there are coding-style issues, then that would fail the build.

I'm currently using:

```
build_failure_conditions:
  - 'issues.label("coding-style").new.exists'
```

[Which makes the inspection look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYi54.png)

More info about how to set-up failure conditions: 
https://scrutinizer-ci.com/docs/configuration/build_status